# Child Component active auto onSubmit parent function

Tags: reactjs, api, components, formik, prop

I have two component, I give my child component as props to my parent component and I want to separate  onSubmit function.

I made a simple example to explain better :

https://codesandbox.io/s/check-it-forked-snm35?file=/src/Weather.js:890-898

Here my problem when I click on **"Get Whether"** I get the next step in my stepper

[[Get Whether]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5E26.png)

**But if I run the Weather component separated this work fine**

[[Weather component ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPFn0.png)

Comment: Add formik to your label will help get better answers

Comment: I added Thank you!